# Using Greasemonkey to Prevent downloading of a script

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

With Greasemonkey, I'm looking to block images and scripts from being downloaded.

From an [existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972038/stop-execution-of-javascript-function-client-side-or-tweak-it) I learnt that it is possible to use the document-start directive to jump in before scripts execute.

Is it possible for me to use `window.addEventListener` on a specific event that allows me to find the `src = xxx.js` and `xxx.jpg` tags and either remove these `src=` tags before downloading, or to block the download?

Note: Here is [a list of events that Mozilla supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/DOM_event_reference).

AMENDED: I would like to replace the blocked downloads with my own scripts or images.

Comment: Use the answer you linked to block the desired `xxx.js` files.  You can use Mutation Observers to quickly kill image `src`s, but the file might start downloading in the background anyway (need to test this). ... The **smart** thing to do is to use [Adblock Plus](http://adblockplus.org/en/), and/or maybe [RequestPolicy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/requestpolicy/) to block select js or jpg files.  Adblock plus will be faster as well.

Comment: Thx ... I still need to investigate these two paths, but I should say that I would like to replace the blocked downloads with my own scripts or images. (Per AMENDED text.)

Comment: Can you run a Greasemonkey script before the page's html is executed? if so, maybe it's possible to remove the desired html elements

Comment: Yes - You can use the script at "document-start". This will allow you to add the event listeners (and do some other activities) before you get the page. At this time, a lot of the HTML is missing. My tests sow that only the <head> elements are filled - I ain't got no <body> for me.

Comment: Greasemonkey can't do this, because the page script may earlier than GM script execute. You remove the `src` attribute later doesn't help. I think what your want is modify the http response content.

Comment: Bad question, you should directly ask you want to replace the scripts and images. Greasemonkey can't do this, try to use https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/redirector/

Comment: I'd recommend trying Ublock Origin instead.  You can write your custom blocking rules for it.