# How can i force website to stay in frame?

Tags: redirect, javascript, firefox

I'm using `Firefox` + `searchbastard` addon to do a multi-search on shopping search engines.The pages are part of a frame. This works just fine for all sites I tried so far except for shopmania.com.

If I use noscript to forbid scripts from the shopmania domain name then everything stays in place but the part of the website elements become nonresponsive. I know there is an option in Firefox to force links that open in a new window to open in a new tab. Is there something similar to prevent websites from popping out of frame? Maybe a Firefox addon that blocks these requests?

Or at least can someone please tell me what is causing only this website to act like this?

EDIT: What tool can i use to pause firefox  OR javascript and stepthrough code like in c++ ? I tried a javascript debugger and firebug. They don't help but  i'm probably not using them right..

EDIT2: I tried this  greasemonkey script : https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/92424. It does not work so i guess it isn't because of 'target' attribute

Comment: Are you developing something? Your question seems off-topic.

Comment: FYI this JS in shop mania's `<head>` section: `if (top != self) {top.location = location;}` is what's breaking your frame.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong. I'm guessing you're using a plugin to capture and override the output some site gives you. I'm pretty sure this violates their ToS and it's not a very nice thing to do in general.

JavaScript is not designed to allow this kind of meddling. It's patchy at best.

If you want to use the data from a website, to aggregate or display in some manner, use their public API. If they don't have a public API they probably don't want you to use their service in such a manner.

Answer (score 0):

The solution : I took the script from [Stop execution of Javascript function (client side) or tweak it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972038/stop-execution-of-javascript-function-client-side-or-tweak-it) and modified it to search for the tag that has in it `top.location = location` and then appended a new script with the if (top != self) {top.location = location;} line commented . Being a js total newbie i don't know if it's the most elegant choice but it soves the prob. Special thanks to Tim Fountain.
I will leave this open just in case someone else will suggest a better solution, for my and others's education. Again thanks for the help.
Below is the code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name _Replace evil Javascript
// @run-at document-start
// ==/UserScript==

/****** New "init" function that we will use
instead of the old, bad "init" function.
*/
function init () {
/* //changing stuff around here 
var newParagraph = document.createElement ('p');
newParagraph.textContent = "I was added by the new, good init() function!";
document.body.appendChild (newParagraph); */
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className+=" js "+(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("webkit")>=0?"webkit":navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("opera")>=0?"opera":"");
for(i in css3_tags="abbr|header|footer".split("|")){document.createElement(css3_tags[i]);}
var PATH = "http://www.shopmania.com";
var PATH_STATIC = "http://im4.shopmania.org";
var PATH_SELF = "http://www.shopmania.com/";
var RETURN = "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.shopmania.com%2F";
var DOMAIN_BASE = "shopmania.com";
var SUBDOMAINS_FORCE_FILES_JS = "aff.remote,biz.remote,my.remote,cp.remote,cp.register_quick,cp.account_details,partner.remote,site.recommend,site.remote,site.feedback,site.report_problem,site.report,site.cropper";
var URL_REWRITE_MAPPING_JS = "cmd,section,do,option|feed,mode,option|forgot,section|info,page|login,section|logout,section|new_password,section,code|settings,section|shopping,param_main,param_sec|site,store_str_key|register,section|unsubscribe,section|agentie,store_str_key,id|brand,manuf_str_key|brands,letter|build,type,param_main,param_sec|compare,online|confirm,section|edit,section|deal,deal|dictionary,online|home,section|link_accounts,section|profile,user|reactivate,section|searches,letter|signup,section|rs_agent,store_str_key|rs_list,param_main,param_sec|rs_view,ad|agents,state|complex_list,param_main|complex_view,complex|list,cat|ad,a|map,option|my_ads,section|my_alerts,section";
var SVR_SITE_ID = "us";
var CONTEXT = "c5b27de70340c97a94092a43bd34b2b8";
var link_close = "Close";
var txt_loading = "Loading...";
var form_is_submitted = 0;
var search_is_focused = 0;
// Overlay object
var OL;
var DB;
var iframe_cnt = "";
// Facebook post to user's Wall action
var FACEBOOK_WALL_FEED_SIGNUP = "";
var SITENAME = "ShopMania";

//if (top != self) {top.location = location;} // SIT!

var comps = new Array();  comps['all'] = 0;var comps_cat_titles = new Array();  var views = new Array(); views['auto'] = 0; views['prod'] = 0; views['realestate'] = 0; views['classifieds'] = 0; views['all'] = 0; var search = new Array();  search['all'] = 0; search['prod'] = 0;
var favs = new Array(); favs['all'] = 0; favs['prod'] = 0; favs['store'] = 0; favs['manuf'] = 0; favs['other'] = 0; favs['realestate'] = 0; favs['auto'] = 0;
function addCss(c){var b=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];var a=document.createElement("style");a.setAttribute("type","text/css");if(a.styleSheet){a.styleSheet.cssText=c}else{a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(c))}b.appendChild(a)};
addCss(".lzl {visibility: hidden;}");
var RecaptchaOptions = { theme : 'clean' }; 
//--><!]]>
}

/*--- Check for bad scripts to intercept and specify any actions to take.
*/
checkForBadJavascripts ( [
[false, /top.location = location/, function () {addJS_Node (init);} ]
] );

function checkForBadJavascripts (controlArray) {
/*--- Note that this is a self-initializing function. The controlArray
parameter is only active for the FIRST call. After that, it is an
event listener.

The control array row is defines like so:
[bSearchSrcAttr, identifyingRegex, callbackFunction]
Where:
bSearchSrcAttr True to search the SRC attribute of a script tag
false to search the TEXT content of a script tag.
identifyingRegex A valid regular expression that should be unique
to that particular script tag.
callbackFunction An optional function to execute when the script is
found. Use null if not needed.
*/
if ( ! controlArray.length) return null;

checkForBadJavascripts = function (zEvent) {

for (var J = controlArray.length - 1; J >= 0; --J) {
var bSearchSrcAttr = controlArray[J][0];
var identifyingRegex = controlArray[J][1];

if (bSearchSrcAttr) {
if (identifyingRegex.test (zEvent.target.src) ) {
stopBadJavascript (J);
return false;
}
}
else {
if (identifyingRegex.test (zEvent.target.textContent) ) {
stopBadJavascript (J);
return false;
}
}
}

function stopBadJavascript (controlIndex) {
zEvent.stopPropagation ();
zEvent.preventDefault ();

var callbackFunction = controlArray[J][2];
if (typeof callbackFunction == "function")
callbackFunction ();

//--- Remove the node just to clear clutter from Firebug inspection.
zEvent.target.parentNode.removeChild (zEvent.target);

//--- Script is intercepted, remove it from the list.
controlArray.splice (J, 1);
if ( ! controlArray.length) {
//--- All done, remove the listener.
window.removeEventListener (
'beforescriptexecute', checkForBadJavascripts, true
);
}
}
}

/*--- Use the "beforescriptexecute" event to monitor scipts as they are loaded.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onbeforescriptexecute
Note that it does not work on acripts that are dynamically created.
*/
window.addEventListener ('beforescriptexecute', checkForBadJavascripts, true);

return checkForBadJavascripts;
}

function addJS_Node (text, s_URL, funcToRun) {
var D = document;
var scriptNode = D.createElement ('script');
scriptNode.type = "text/javascript";
if (text) scriptNode.textContent = text;
if (s_URL) scriptNode.src = s_URL;
if (funcToRun) scriptNode.textContent = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';

var targ = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
//--- Don't error check here. if DOM not available, should throw error.
targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}
```

there are some escaping issues with the cdata part in the code.So SO does not allow me to post the code.
EDIT: fixed

Comment: works now thanks. I initially thought you're supposed to use ctrl+k AND use <code></code>