# Change window.location prototype to disable certain redirects?

Tags: javascript, prototype, greasemonkey, window.location

I'm trying to selectively disable `window.location`, using Greasemonkey, at the start of the document.

I don't want to fully disable javascript, just disable some redirects done with javascript.  They look like this:

```
window.location = "unwanted url";
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: How are the redirects being done, ***exactly***?  There's at least 5 possible ways.

Comment: @brock, window.location=urltoredirect; (at)crazy I want to stop some redirections without disabling javascript...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the `window.location` prototype, because this a "native property" of `window` and it is [not *configurable*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

On Firefox (Greasemonkey), if you try to override this then you will get errors like:

> TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property 'location'

and

> Error: Permission denied to shadow native property

...depending on how you attempt it.  Other browsers give similar errors.

---

To block this kind of relocation, you need to interfere with the page's javascript on a case-by-case basis.

See ["Stop execution of Javascript function (client side) or tweak it"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10468821/331508) for a general approach that works in Firefox.  Although it may be much easier, depending on your target page's exact code.

Comment: alright, this works when it's <script>content</script>, but what about <script src="url"></script>? is there a way to stop it too?

Comment: Yes, [checkForBadJavascripts()](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2620135) has a mode that does that.  Or, you could just use Adblock to block that exact script URL.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think it's possible.

- You can't overwrite properties or methods on `window.location` (fails silently)
- you can't redefine its prototype with `location.__proto__ = Something.prototype`
- `location.constructor.prototype` is basically `Object.prototype`
- the constructor doesn't really do anything (like create the attributes or methods)
- `__definesetter__` fails silently
- `Object.defineProperty` gives an error like, `TypeError: Cannot redefine property: href`
- `delete window.location` and `delete window.location.href` don't do anything

I'm out of ideas...

Comment: This sucks! Seems that nothing has changed in 2016  :-(

Answer (score -3):

quite too late but you can do it simply without removing the whole script with `Object.prototype.watch`:

```
window.watch('location', function( attr ,_ , target){
    if(target.indexOf('unwanted url') !== -1)return '#';
});
```

Comment: "TypeError: can't watch objects of non-native class Proxy"

Comment: cannot watch window or other paths to location

Comment: This function is implemented only in Gecko as the op asked.And there was a bug in Firefox 23 to 27 that causes this type error but it's now fixed.

Comment: This does not work in FF 49, if it ever did at all.  JS redirects still function with no interference.