# Enable and disable window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recently, YouTube introduced the new Autoplay feature and I got jealous.

[image]

I implemented it on my tube site. My site uses jwplayer as a video player, it has a very beautiful and easy API where a function there is called onComplete, where it will execute my javascript queries at the end of the video.

What I did is this:

```
onComplete:function() {
//Video has ended, now we redirect to the new video
window.location.href = "//www.mysite.com/video?id=33412";
}
```

So, using this, my site will successfully redirect to a new video, and so on. But, what if the user turns off the  "Autoplay" feature as shown in the image. How can I disable the window.location.href?

Other stackoverflow answers [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18285835/2922834):

> You can't change the window.location prototype, because this a "native property" of window and it is not configurable.

What would be the solution in my case? A solution using Jquery is okay for me too.

Comment: Why don't you set a flag for autoplay. in oncomplete check the flag before window.location.href

Comment: What do you mean by _disable the window.location.href_?

Comment: @mohamedrias solution is all you need, it's only needed a single flag...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `autoplay` have a flag. Set/unset the flag.

In your onComplete, check the flag

```
onComplete:function() {
//Video has ended, now we redirect to the new video

// check the flag and execute
if(autoPlay) window.location.href = "//www.mysite.com/video?id=33412";

}
```

Comment: Ah, how dumb I was. :)

Answer (score 3):

You will need to store some state somewhere, such as this:

```
var autoplayEnabled = true;

$('#autoplay-toggle').on('click', function() {
    autoplayEnabled = ! autoplayEnabled;
});

// . . .
{
    onComplete: function() {
        // Video has ended, now we redirect to the new video
        if (autoplayEnabled) {
            window.location.href = "//www.mysite.com/video?id=33412";
        }
    }
}
```

When they click on the autoplay trigger it'll toggle the global variable which you then check against in the onComplete callback.

Comment: (jQuery used because of the question tags - other event handlers are available.)