# Debug minified and obfuscated Javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging, greasemonkey, obfuscation

I have a Javascript function which is minified and obfuscated and even the Javascript debuggers with it's functionality to beautify the code aren't really working. There are a lot of eval codes and things like this. 
I need to debug this code step by step and my solution is to beautify the script by myself at first. After that when I request the normal web page I want to change the location of the real Javascript at the server through my local, beautfied Javascript. So I can debug this one. I thought about using Browser Addons like Greasemonkey to replace the "src" attribute of the script, but I'm not familiar with the technology behind GreaseMonkey, so I even don't know if it would work.

Do you have any good solutions for my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to replace the js on the server with your modified js temporarily?

Comment: Exactly. Just for debug purposes.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3972038/331508). Also, try debugging the original page using Chrome.  The Chrome debugging tools are better (for the original, non beautified, JS).