# How I can force a website to use the latest version of CKEditor.js with a Userscript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, greasemonkey, userscripts

I'm new to CKEditor and relatively new to JavaScript.

I'd like to make a script/Userscript to force some sites that already use CKEditor to use the latest version of ckeditors.js to be able to use the new features.

A good example is http://www.pageorama.com which use the old 3.6.2 version.

You can see the version easily with `alert(CKEDITOR.version);`

I already know how to destroy CKEditor instance with `CKEDITOR.instances.editor.destroy()`  and add things to the toolbar.

My main problem now is to have the latest CKEditor version to be used when I reload it with `CKEDITOR.replace(editor);` , This was I will be able to config it with the latest feature on site that use CKEditor.

How I can do that ?

Comment: Suspect you would have  lot of problems due the way config is set to pull in resource files. Also you don't know if site is using internal methods during submit process for example. Why would you need to do this in the first place?

Comment: I've already tested to destroy/recreate the editor a saving file with contents and it work fine, no problem at all like I expected :)   

With the variables for the config you can change almost anything in the configuration.

All I need now to complete my project is find a way have the latest CKEditor.js to be loaded.when I invoke `CKEDITOR.replace(editor);`

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer and it's fairly easy to do.

If fact I just have to modify the Original JavaScript in the HTML code that load the CKEditor.js and modify it to load the latest version you need.

**The complete instruction are here:** [Stop execution of Javascript function (client side) or tweak it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972038/stop-execution-of-javascript-function-client-side-or-tweak-it)