# How do I remove/modify a javascript function before it executes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, greasemonkey, adblock

I just came across https://www.hotslogs.com, who uses javascript to redirect to the adblock page if the ad does not work properly.

Its source code looks like this

```js
function FillMonkeyBrokerHorizontal01() {}

function nb6fda3f1(src) { //function name is randomly generated     
  if (true) {
    var jqueryWindow = $(window);
    jqueryWindow.attr("location", "/Info/AdBloc" + "k?Sour" + "ce=" + src);
  } else
    ga("send", "event", "AdFillMonkeyBroker", "Ad Blocked Acceptably", {
      nonInteraction: true
    });
}

//other if-conditions calls this function
```

My first thought is to modify this function to a function that does nothing. I tried the solution in [Stop execution of Javascript function (client side) or tweak it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972038/stop-execution-of-javascript-function-client-side-or-tweak-it) and the example on [jsbin.com/ogudon/1](http://jsbin.com/ogudon/1) worked for me.

However when I tried my solution

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        hotslogs.com adblock killer killer
// @description hotslogs.com adblock killer killer
// @include     https://www.hotslogs.com/*
// @run-at      document-start
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

checkForBadJavascripts([
  [TRUE,
    /mb105.gz.js/, alert("intercepted mb105.gz.js");
  ]
  [FALSE,
    /AdBloc/, alert("intercepted adbloc function");
  ]
]);

//checkForBadJavascripts definitions,etc.
```

It did not work well, the page redirects to adblock page and no alert was triggered. I am not sure if it is due to the before/afterscriptexecute not supported in HTML5 standard or if I missed anything. Any suggestions or alternative solutions?

Comment: If the function is in the global scope, you can just override the function. If not, that will be much harder.

Comment: found a solution that works:https://gist.github.com/slacker/07d2e48b5c73a95828c3ccb61e98f959