# GreaseMonkey - Prevent online script

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have an HTML website which returns some HTML like this:

```
<div id="content">Content ... 
  <div id="badscript">
   <script>badscript();</script> 
  </div> ...
</div>
```

With GreaseMonkey for Firefox is it possibile to prevent that **badscript** is executed?

Comment: Specifically the [answer by CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59518023).

Comment: It doesn't work because "To modify inline <script>// code here</script> tags, you'll have to download a local copy of the page. (So if the page serves dynamic content through the HTML response, you'll either have to re-save and re-tweak the .html for your overrides to use the new content, or you'll have to go back to the MutationObserver method.)"

Comment: No, that note is for the alternative method via overrides, you don't need that.