# getElementsByTagName() and others not returning all elements that they should?

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

I'm a novice JavaScript user and I'm currently writing a [Tampermonkey](http://www.tampermonkey.net/) script that retrieves a `<script>` tag from the document header and edits it. It's set to execute before all other scripts on the page so I can edit some configuration values before the other scripts pick them up. The script works on some sites, but not others, despite the element I need being present on all the sites I've tried. I'm using `document.head.getElementsByTagName('script')` to get all script tags in the header that I'll eventually iterate over, but it always returns a list that is missing several tags. These are the only lines I'm running right now:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var scptTags = document.head.getElementsByTagName('script');
    console.log(scptTags);
})();
```

At first, I thought that the element I needed wasn't there initially, and instead was being written to the DOM during page load. But if I curl the document, I can see that the element is there. Since I'm running the script at [`document-start`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_run_at), it should be able to see this tag every time, but that's not the case.

I tried using several other methods including iterating through document.head.childNodes (which also missed several elements) and searching through the whole document instead of just the header. When I use `console.log(document.head.innerHTML);` in the script, I can see that the header is incomplete even though the closing `</head>` and `</html>` tags are there.

Then I noticed that if I pause the request for a moment in [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) before it gets to Chrome, more tags are loaded into the header as if something needed more time (and this is before any other scripts are running on the page). But why would the script execute before the browser had fully loaded the page into memory? It seems so random and strange that I must be missing something. Is this an issue with my methods, or possibly with Chrome?

I'm using the latest version of Chrome Dev (86.0.4229.0) on Ubuntu 20.10. One of the pages I observed this behavior on is docs.google.com, particularly while loading a document.

Comment: If you use instant `document-start`, the userscript should run before anything in the DOM is populated - the `document.head` won't exist yet. Also note that to "edit" a script tag like it sounds like you're wanting to do, you'll need to use a MutationObserver - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59518023

Comment: @CertainPerformance Using a MutationObserver fixed this issue for me and made getting the tag much easier. Thank you!