# Is there a way to run a content script after the page is loaded but before scripts are executed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

I'm writing a browser extension to intercept all the script tags on the page when it's loaded, but before they execute. To be clear, I'm not looking to block the scripts entirely; I just want to intercept and analyze/modify them before they're run.

Is there a way to do this?

I'm aware of `onbeforescriptexecute` for Firefox and its polyfill for Chrome, but I'm hoping for something more "official" and cross-browser...

Comment: [MutationObserver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59518023), maybe

Comment: Perhaps a [DOMContentLoaded Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event).

Comment: @StackSlave I don't think that can be utilized to target specific scripts.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Perfect!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by [CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance) in the comments, you can use a MutationObserver to observe changes to the DOM as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59518023