# How to inspect which js is consuming/decrypting websocket messages?

Tags: javascript, encryption, websocket, google-chrome-devtools

I've been trying to understand how the websocket messages are decrypted by js.

https://1win.com.ci/casino/play/aviator

The websocket messages really seem to be encrypted. For example:

gABuEgADAAFwEgACAAFwEgADAA1jdXJyZW50UGF5b3V0B0AUAAAAAAAAAARjb2RlBAAAAMgAD2N1cnJlbnRHYW1lVGltZQUAAAAAAABLyAABYwgAEWN1cnJlbnRNdWx0aXBsaWVyAAFhAwANAAFjAgE==

Decoding it to utf-8 does not return the needed info, so I'm trying to reverse engineer it to find out which js script is consuming the websocket messages and maybe find a way to decrypt it.

So far i've tried using Chrome Dev Tools by adding a breakpoint on the element that is modified (the big multiplier in the middle of the screen), but I couldn't find what part of the code consumes and maybe decrypts the message.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run some code before the page code runs, which can be done with [either Chrome Local Overrides or a userscript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59518023).

It depends on how the page listens to messages. If it assigns to the `onmessage` property of the socket instance, you can overwrite the setter with your own setter that traces the caller - you could use `console.trace`, or `throw new Error`.

```
Object.defineProperty(WebSocket.prototype, 'onmessage', {
  set(newVal) {
    throw new Error();
  }
});
```

Then just open the console, look at the stack trace of the thrown error, and you'll be in the general location of where the message gets parsed - perhaps the decryption is done there, or perhaps the payload gets passed to another function that does the decryption. If the page's script is large, it'll help to use a good IDE that allows you to jump to function definitions by their references. (eg, in VSCode - right click an identifier, then select **Go to definition**).

If the message listener gets attached with `addEventListener` instead, you can monkeypatch `WebSocket.prototype.addEventListener` and use the same technique.

```
WebSocket.prototype.addEventListener = function(eventName, callback) {
  if (eventName === 'message') {
    throw new Error();
  }
};
```

One of the above approaches will show you where the message enters the page's script. Since you already know how to get to where the message *exits* the page script (and gets put into the DOM), you now have a starting point and an ending point, and can work backwards and forwards until they meet.

That's for the general approach. For this particular situation, it looks like it's encoded with some variation on Base64, because I can see that the payload in your question [contains the words](https://www.base64decode.org/) `currentPayout`, `code`, `currentGameTime`, and `currentMultiplier`.