# Is it possible to debug JS when the URL keeps changing?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I'm trying to debug the JavaScript of a website which references some JS via a random URL path each pageload.  This makes Chrome think that the JS is a different document, but I can see the same JS is being served up each time.  However, breakpoints don't stay because the URL is different.

Is there a way I can get breakpoints to stay somehow between page loads of the same JS with different URL paths, or maybe break on function name instead of the normal way?

Comment: Options outside Chrome's debugger include Fiddler I think, or [a userscript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59518023)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way i think is to put

```
debugger;
```

everywhere you wanted the breakpoint. As you have rightly understood that the browser considers it as a new file, and there is no way to tell the browser that it is same file when the URL is different.